# How can I initialize a record declared as a local variable?

Tags: delphi

I'm using a record composed of strings, booleans, integers, currencies and arrays of other records inside a method of a class. I would like to recursively initialize all fields of a primitive type to empty/false/zero. Delphi doesn't appear to do this by default. Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this that doesn't involve accessing each field by name and setting it manually?

Comment: Note that Delphi initializes lifetime-managed types (strings, dynamic arrays, interfaces).

Comment: In Delphi-2009 and later a record can be initialized by `Foo := Default(TFoo);`. See [David's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066205/576719) to the question [How to properly free records that contain various types in Delphi at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11065821/576719).

Comment: also see: [Which variables are initialized when in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861045/which-variables-are-initialized-when-in-delphi)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use *either one* of following constructs (where Foo is a record).

```
FillChar(Foo, SizeOf(Foo), 0); 

ZeroMemory(@Foo, SizeOf(Foo));
```

From a post from [Allen Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783825/why-most-delphi-examples-use-fillchar-to-initialize-records)

> While looking at the most common uses
>   for FillChar in order to determine
>   whether most folks use FillChar to
>   actually fill memory with character
>   data or just use it to initialize
>   memory with some given byte value, we
>   found that it was the latter case that
>   dominated its use rather than the
>   former. With that we decided to keep
>   FillChar byte-centric.

Comment: Or same code with (probably) better readability:

    ZeroMemory(@Foo, SizeOf(Foo));

Comment: @Im0rtality: I have updated the answer to include your ZeroMemory solution.

Comment: Note that ZeroMemory is a wrapper for FillChar in *some* versions of Delphi (d6 and 7 at least).

Comment: You should not use this, when the record contains managed types like strings or interfaces

Answer (score 2):

Note, that [you should use Finalize before FillChar or ZeroMemory in *some* cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250827/initialise-string-function-result/3251381#3251381).

Answer (score 1):

well, you may apply a simple legal trick

```
unit unit1;

interface

type
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
  TMyRecord = record
    Value: Integer;
    function Self: PMyRecord;
  end;

implementation

function TMyRecord.Self: PMyRecord;
begin
  Result := @Self;
end;

procedure Test(AValue: Integer);
const MyRecord: TMyRecord = (Value: 0);
begin
  MyRecord.Self.Value := AValue;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Delphi 2007, you can use the `Default()` intrinsic function:

```
var
  LRecord: TMyRecord;
begin
  LRecord := Default(TMyRecord);
  ...
```