# Record in record (Cannot initialize)

Tags: delphi

I have 2 records like this:

```
TYPE
 TRecord2= packed record
  i2: Integer;
 end;

 TRecord1= packed record
  i1: Integer;
  R2: TRecord2;
 end;
```

.

I want to initialize the record fields to zero but I don't want to use FillMemory so I declared 2 constant records in which I initialize the fields.

```
CONST
  Record2c: TRecord2=
  (
   i2: 0;
  );

  Record1c: TRecord1=
  (
    i1: 0;
    R2: Record2c;      <------- error line
  );
```

However, I cannot assign a Record2c to R2 field. The compiler says:  E2029 '(' expected but identifier 'Record2c' found.

But this works (if I comment the line where I have the error):

```
procedure test;
var Record1: TRecord1;
begin
 Record1:= Record1c;      // initialize variable by associating the constant to it
end
```

So, how do i initialize the R2 field?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to pack records? Memory can be slower that way.

Comment: That record is to be written to disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only initialize consts with *true constants*. True constants do not have types — those are *typed constants*. See [*Declared Constants*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants) in the Delphi documentation. `Record2c` in your code is a typed constant, so it cannot be used in const expressions like the one required for initializing `Record1c`. You'll just have to in-line the definition of `Record1c.R2`:

```
const
  Record1c: TRecord1 = (
    i1: 0;
    R2: (i2: 0;);
  );
```

When you comment out the error line, you're leaving the `R2` field default-initialized to zeros.

Comment: Thanks. It is not exactly what I hoped for but it will do it. Accepted.

Comment: And another question: if the R2 filed will be declared like this "R2: array[1..1024] of Byte" how do I fill it with zeros?

Comment: That would have been better as a separate question: "How do I initialize an array field of a record constant?" Anyway, you initialize it with a list of values: `R2: (0, 0, 0, ...)`. Any items you don't specify will be set to zero. That only works with fixed-size arrays; the only constant expression allowed for dynamic arrays is `nil`.

Comment: Added as new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667907/how-to-initialize-a-static-array

Answer (score 5):

That's because `Record2c` is a **typed** constant which isn't a "real" constant. So you can't use it to initialize another constant. You have to declare `Record1c` like

```
  Record1c: TRecord1 =
    (
    i1: 0;
    R2: (i2: 0);
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi-2009 and later it is possible to zero a record by the `Default` call.

```
record1 := Default(TRecord1);  // This will zero record1 including R2
```

See [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066205/576719) to the question [How to properly free records that contain various types in Delphi at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11065821/576719).