# How to initialize a static array?

Tags: delphi

Let's say I have this declaration:

```
TYPE
 RDisk= packed record
   R2: array[1..1024] of Byte;
   etc
   etc
  end;
```

How do I initialize R2 to zero using a constant declaration like this:

```
CONST
 Disk: RDisk= 
   (
    R: ??
   );
```

This is related to [Record in record (Cannot initialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667187/record-in-record-cannot-initialize)

Comment: Type declarations use `=`, not `:`. Is that a type or a variable declaration? In your previous question, you made it sound like that was supposed to be a field of a record. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omit the fields you want to zero:

```
type
 RDisk= packed record
   R2: array[1..512] of Byte;
   I: Integer;
   D: Double;
   R3: array[1..512] of Byte;
  end;

const
 Disk: RDisk=
   (
    I: 3;
    D: 2.5;
   );
```

or,

```
const
 Disk: RDisk=
   (
   );
```

I don't know why it works, it doesn't quite fit in [Record Constants'](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Record_Constants) documentation.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I just hope it isn't a 'hack' that will not work anymore in future versions of Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize an array with zero using this

```
ZeroMemory(@R2[0],length(R2));
```

or this

```
FillChar(R2[0],length(R2),0);
```

Comment: Why would FillChar be unsafe? Just FillChar the array, not the entire record, and it is fully safe. FillChar is only unsafe for types that are not "blittable", i.e. types that require special handling, like strings, interfaces, variants, etc.

Comment: Yep i perfectly agree with rudy

Comment: Use of FillChar is unsafe because it's too easy to make mistakes.  What if I use it on an array of records with no strings ("safe"), and then the next programmer adds a string to the record?  Additionally, there's the easy mistake of confusing length() with SizeOf().

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - See comment from GuyGordon. That's why :) :) :)

Comment: You can make mistakes in almost every line of code. Not really a good reason not to use a low level procedure. FillChar is no more unsafe than ZeroMemory.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a constant of type `R2` and initialize it to all zeros like this:

```
const
  zeros: R2 = (0, 0, 0, ...);
```

The array length is 1024, so you must specify all 1024 comma-separated values in that list.

Comment: If I set fewer values then I get error":E2072 Number of elements (3) differ from declaration (1024)".

Comment: @Rob: you have to specify exactly 1024 values. That's how those consts work.

Comment: Seriously? Sorry, I guess I've been using C too long.