# How to finalize record passed through the untyped parameter of a function?

Tags: delphi, record, delphi-6, finalize

Can I pass "any" record type to my procedure ?

Many times I used "records" with strings.

```
type 
  TR = record
    a: string;
    b: string;
  end;
```

To clear them, I need to write:

```
Finalize(R);
FillChar(R, SizeOf(R), #0);
```

The question is that how to I pass any kind of records to clear it ?

For this I got this hint: "Expression needs no initialize/finalize".

```
procedure ClearRecord(var R);
begin
  Finalize(R);
  FillChar(R, SizeOf(R), #0);
end;
```

Thanks for every info!

Comment: I didn't initially spot the untyped parameter. You can't do anything generic like that with an untyped parameter. @LURD's answer looks good to me.

Comment: Your procedure `ClearRecord` gets a raw pointer to some data, but absolutely no info about what it contains. It should be possible to pass `TypeInfo(R)` as a second argument and read the record layout from that, but I fully agree with LU RD's answer that this is far too complicated to be worth the effort.

Comment: @hvd You can use `InitializeArray(@R, TypeInfo(TR), 1)` to achieve that, but yes, plain old assignment is best.

Comment: I wonder why it is required at all. I am always a little suspicious if I see code that finalizes things when this is usually done automatically, by the runtime. So I wonder what "clever" tricks the user is up to. If he really knows what he is doing, he won't have to ask.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Delphi 7 doesn't have that, so I'm guessing Delphi 6 doesn't either. (But I didn't know about it, so thanks, always nice to learn something new.)

Comment: @hvd It's there in D6, you just have to use some hacks to call it!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `_InitializeArray` is, but `InitializeArray` isn't. Accessing `_InitializeArray` is possible with inline assembly, but if you go that route, you can access `_InitializeRecord` directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not make it overly complicated. If you don't want to write a two-liner to clear the record, consider declaring:

```
Const TR_Empty: TR = ();
```

and use it:

```
R := TR_Empty;
```

And as commented by others, a generic procedure to do this is not worth the effort.

If you would have Delphi-2009 or newer, this code is valid for clearing a record:

```
R := Default(TR);
```

Comment: @TLama, see David's answer here: [How to properly free records that contain various types in Delphi at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066205/576719).

Comment: Not just overly complicated, but what durumdara is doing is probably fragile.